# Term for "diagram whose functor isn't injective"?

Tags: category-theory

When I was first trying to understand "diagrams as functors", it really confused me how the diagram could contain multiple copies of an object. Then I realized that this just means that the functor isn't injective, and that you therefore cannot just discard the functor for its image.

Is there a term for diagrams that contain repetitions? If for no other reason than to be explicit that the diagram is the functor itself and not its image.

Comment: What do you mean by "injective functor"?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg It seems "injective" means "injective on objects".

Comment: There is no special term for this. It is just understood that diagrams do not need to be injective on objects, isomorphism classes of objects, or morphisms.

Comment: I mean injective in the usual sense: no two inputs have the same output. Functors take multiple types of input.